# Does Live Web Audio Input work in Google Chrome on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, webkitaudiocontext

According to this article the following code should work on OSX and Windows but doesn't mention Linux:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled

```
// success callback when requesting audio input stream
function gotStream(stream) {
    var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    var mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource( stream );

    // Connect it to the destination to hear yourself (or any other node for processing!)
    mediaStreamSource.connect( audioContext.destination );
}

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia( {audio:true}, gotStream );
```

I downloaded Chrome Dev which is version: Version 25.0.1323.1 dev and it's not working.

I have the following flag enabled:

```
Web Audio Input Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
Enables live audio input using getUserMedia() and the Web Audio API.
```

Comment: As far as I know it should work. Have you tried enabling this experimental feature in chorme://flags and then restarting chrome?

Comment: Yes, I did but I think it's not even needed anymore: https://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/blog/seeyouontheweb Are you using Ubuntu and is it working for you?

Comment: No I'm not on Ubuntu, sorry. Besides that you have the wrong input method, I couldn't think of why it isn't working besides no built in support in the Linux version. I checked my install of Chrome (on Mac OSX) and in chrome-flags there is an extra flag **for Audio specifically**.

Comment: My question is to see if there is built in support for Linux.

Comment: Have you checked the flags to see if you have the specific Audio flag/ enabled

Comment: Yes, I did as I said in my first comment.

Comment: There probably is not support for Web Audio then. Maybe you need to build from source with that feature enabled...

Comment: I also face the same problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/discuss-webrtc/b9Vmuo5znoo

any success stories on windows (i didn't try yet on a Mac though)?

Thanks, Ram

Comment: @RamsundarKandasamy no luck on windows 7 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux support for live audio was added in https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=192893&view=revision.

Currently works on Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.89 beta. Tested on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

As of chrome Version 24.0.1312.69 and Dartium Version 26.0.1403.0 (chromium derivative), I could not manage to make any demo from http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/ using Live Input work on Ubuntu 12.10. I have the proper chrome://flags enabled.

For me it works fine on MacOS but it fails on Ubuntu using either a microphone or a USB camera. Ubuntu Sound Recorder works fine though so I know my hardware is working.

It would be nice to know whether it is supposed to work on Linux or when it is planned to be officially supported.

Answer (score 1):

I can verify this as well. Created ticket on the official Chromium bug tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177862